# Showing Equivalence between a Proposition and the Axiom of Choice

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to establish the equivalence between the following statement and the Axiom of Choice:

> Suppose that $R$ is a relation between two non-empty sets $A$ and $B$. There is a function $F$ with the same domain as $R$ such that $F \subseteq R$.

I have established the direction from the Axiom of Choice to this statement. My proof goes as follows.

For each set $x$, we may define the following set:
\begin{equation*}
A_{x} = \left\{y \in B: \langle x,y \rangle \in R\right\}.
\end{equation*}
Specifically, if $x \in \operatorname{dom}\left(R\right)$, then $A_{x} \neq \emptyset$.
Further, we may define the following set:
\begin{equation*}
S = \left\{A_{x}: x \in \operatorname{dom}\left(R\right)\right\}.
\end{equation*}
It is obvious that $S$ is a set of non-empty sets and $\bigcup{S} \subseteq B$. According to the Axiom of Choice, there is a function $h: S \to \bigcup{S}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\left(\forall T \in S\right)\left(h\left(T\right) \in T\right).
\end{equation*}
We may define a function $F: \operatorname{dom}\left(A\right) \to B$ such that
\begin{equation*}
F\left(x\right) = h\left(A_{x}\right),\ x \in \operatorname{dom}\left(R\right).
\end{equation*}
It is obvious that $F \subseteq R$.

I am wondering how to establish the reverse direction. I understand that there are already several equivalent forms of the Axiom of Choice. For instance, the following statement is the axiom used in my proof above:

> Suppose that $\mathscr{F}$ is a family of non-empty sets. There is a function $h: \mathscr{F} \to \bigcup{\mathscr{F}}$ such that for each $A \in \mathscr{F}$, $h\left(A\right) \in A$.

We also have the following versions:

> Suppose that $\mathscr{F}$ is a family of disjoint non-empty sets. There is a function $h: \mathscr{F} \to \bigcup{\mathscr{F}}$ such that for each $A \in \mathscr{F}$, $h\left(A\right) \in A$.

> Suppose that $M$ is a non-empty set. Then there is a function $h: \mathscr{P}\left(M\right)\setminus \left\{\emptyset\right\} \to M$ such that for all non-empty subsets $A$ of $M$, $h\left(A\right) \in A$.

Can anyone help with completing the proof?

Answer (score 0):

Assume $M$ is a non-empty set, and apply the condition to the relation $$R = \{(A,B) \in (\mathscr P(M) \setminus \{\emptyset\}) \times M : B \in A\}.$$